# Converting a UL LI Single Select Box to a Multiple Select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I really need the help of an expert here on this site. I'd like to be able to, add on and build functionality such that my custom UL LI single select boxes, would be able to handle multiple user selections.

Here's the typical scenario, the user holds down the CTRL Key on their keyboard and selects multiple values from the select box.

Here is a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c2ezuw24/1/

Here is the existing Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; font-size:0.75em; color:#000;}

        .dropdown dd, .dropdown dt, .dropdown ul {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
        .dropdown dd {
            position:relative;
        }
        .dropdown a, .dropdown a:visited { color:#816c5b; text-decoration:none; outline:none;}

        .dropdown a:hover { color:#000;}

        .dropdown dt a:hover, .dropdown dt a:focus {
            border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);
        }

        .dropdown dt a {
            background:#e4dfcb url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
            display:block;
            padding-right:20px;
            border:1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
            width:150px;
        }
        .dropdown dt a span {
            cursor:pointer;
            display:block;
            padding:5px;
        }
        .dropdown dd ul {
           background:#e4dfcb none repeat scroll 0 0;
           border:1px solid rgb(170,170,170);

           display:none;
           left:0px;
           padding:5px 0px;
           position:absolute;
           top:2px;
           width:auto;
           min-width:170px;
           list-style:none;
       }
        .dropdown span.value { display:none;}
        .dropdown dd ul li a { padding:5px; display:block;}
        .dropdown dd ul li a:hover { background-color:#d0c9af;}

        .dropdown img.flag { border:none; vertical-align:middle; margin-left:10px; }
        .flagvisibility { display:none;}


    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".dropdown img.flag").addClass("flagvisibility");

            $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
                $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
            });

            $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
                var text = $(this).html();
                $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
                $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
                $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
            });

            function getSelectedValue(id) {
                return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
            }

            $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
                var $clicked = $(e.target);
                if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
                    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
            });


            $("#flagSwitcher").click(function() {
                $(".dropdown img.flag").toggleClass("flagvisibility");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <dl id="sample" class="dropdown">
        <dt><a href="#"><span>Please select the country</span></a></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Brazil<img class="flag" src="br.png" alt="" /><span class="value">BR</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">France<img class="flag" src="fr.png" alt="" /><span class="value">FR</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Germany<img class="flag" src="de.png" alt="" /><span class="value">DE</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">India<img class="flag" src="in.png" alt="" /><span class="value">IN</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Japan<img class="flag" src="jp.png" alt="" /><span class="value">JP</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Serbia<img class="flag" src="cs.png" alt="" /><span class="value">CS</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">United Kingdom<img class="flag" src="gb.png" alt="" /><span class="value">UK</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">United States<img class="flag" src="us.png" alt="" /><span class="value">US</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <span id="result"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

use built in html feature.
http://jsfiddle.net/2v8foz90/

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="DEDE">Hello</option>
  <option value="FEFE">bonjour</option>
  <option value="SESE">Ciao</option>
  <option value="AEAE">hallo</option>
</select>
```